# RequireJS/Backbone: How to pass data into a require

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I've got a Backbone event that includes:

```
this.model.save()
    .done(function(response) {
        require(['models/countModel', 'views/countView'], function(cm, cv, response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
     });
    .fail(function(response) {
         ...
     });
```

`console.log(response)` yields undefined.  I need the response from the server so I can process the data.  How do I get to it?  But if I `console.log()` it above the `require` then I get to the response from the server.  How do I pass it in?  What I am doing does not work.  I don't think that's how a `require` is intended to work, but I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass response as reference with require, as it's already defined when done is called. Change your require call to:

```
require(['models/countModel', 'views/countView'], function(cm, cv) {
```

should do the trick!